# My mvc 2 application serves 404 for all pages except home page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, iis-6

I have an mvc 2 application that is running in ii6 in the test environment and production server.

The test enviroment runs just fine, but after moving to production all pages except the home page server up 404 errors.

I have followed step 2, here: http://blog.codeville.net/2008/07/04/options-for-deploying-aspnet-mvc-to-iis-6/  and added a .aspx extension to the route, and have tried the wildcard mapping. It doesn't appear to make any difference.

I put the diagnostic file found here: http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/03/diagnosing-aspnet-mvc-problems.html  into the directory and loaded it, but it does not report any errors or problems.

I even wiped the test server and reinstalled the app from scractch, setup the wildcard mapping and it worked fine.

Right now the pages are being routed like: `Home.aspx/About`  and my routing table looks like this:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{*favicon}", new { favicon = @"(.*/)?favicon.ico(/.*)?" });

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}.aspx/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );
    routes.MapRoute(
        "NewEmployee",
        "{controller}.aspx/{action}",
        new { controller = "NewEmployee", action = "Index" }
    );
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Admin",
        "{controller}.aspx/{action}",
        new { controller = "Admin", action = "Index" });
    routes.MapRoute(
        "AccessMaster",
        "{controller}.aspx/{action}/{id}/{subid}",
        new { controller = "AccessMaster", action = "Index", id=UrlParameter.Optional,subid=UrlParameter.Optional });

    routes.MapRoute(
      "Root",
      "",
      new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }
    );

}
```

**I'm at a loss here.  Am I doing something wrong? Is there something wrong with the server?**

Comment: I think you have a lot of overlapping routes. How about removing all those after "Default" ? But post the exact error message, you're probably missing 1 or more files.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize that. Do you think it could be causing the problem here? It wouldn't explain why it works fine in the test server.

Comment: The only error message is a 404 response code from the server on anything except the base virtual directory address. Anything with a route like `home/about` returns 404.

Comment: Is your Home.Index.aspx in the same folder as the other views?

Comment: `Views\Home\Index.aspx` is in the same folder as `Views\Home\About.aspx`, yes.

Comment: Do you have an ISAPI filter in use for other applications on the same server? If so, the rules configured in the ISAPI filter might be catching the requests to your MVC site.

Comment: I checked that acutally, and no, nothing like that. I just got back from deleting the folder, republishing, and deleting and recreating the virtual directory. Guess what? It's working now.  I've been pulling my hair out for days. I think I'm going to go cry now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like deleting and recreating the virtual directory magically fixed whatever was wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

Try registering ASP.NET with IIS using the following command:

```
aspnet_regiis /i
```

Also make sure that you have enabled the correct version of ASP.NET in IIS (Web Service Extensions folder):

[image]

You also have many unnecessary routes routes. For example the `NewEmployee` and `Admin` routes are totally equivalent meaning that only the first route in this list will ever be matched. But that's another problem, it is unrelated to the deployment errors you are getting. You could fix your routes once you make your application successfully run.

Comment: .net 4 is not installed on either servers. The project is build with mvc2 on the 3.5 client framework. Asp.net v2.0.50727 is set to Allowed like above.

Comment: Will running the reregister affect any other applications on the server? I cannot do anything that might cause any outages to the other applications.

Comment: @asawyer, it will recycle them.

Comment: Gotcha. Do you think it might help?  There is another 2.0 clr app running on it now without any problems.

Comment: @asawyer, not sure. It was just something that came to my mind. I am by far not an expert in configuring IIS. Your question might be better suited to http://serverfault.com if you have problems configuring your web server. StackOverflow is more suited for problems with programming which you doesn't seem to have.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll give it a shot over there. Appreciated the help.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/304207/my-mvc-2-application-serves-404-for-all-pages-except-home-page-iis-6